# React undefined errors

Tags: reactjs

Full code [here](https://github.com/3noki/project_5_react_bookshelf_app)

I am getting errors for udpateShelf is not defined, but Changeshelf is imported and it has properties assigned in the function, I'm so confused, why am I still getting undefined errors? I feel like I'm not understanding fully how react passes props through the components, if someone cane explain that better I feel that will help me with creating different components or functions for this app.

Bookshelf.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Books from './Books.js'
import logo from '../icons/logo.svg'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import ChangeShelf from "./ChangeShelf.js"

const shelves = [
  { key: 'currentlyReading',
    name: 'Currently Reading' },
  { key: 'wantToRead',
    name: 'Want to Read' },
  { key: 'read',
    name: 'Read' }
]

export default class Bookshelf extends Component {

static propTypes = {
  book: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  books: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  updateShelf: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

render() {
  const { book, books, shelfkey } = this.props;

  return (

  <div className="list-books">
      <div className="react-app">
        <header className="App-header">
        <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
        <h1 className="App-title">React bookshelf app</h1>
        </header>
      </div>

        <div className="list-books-title">
          <h1>my bookshelf</h1>
        </div>

    <div className="list-books-content">
      {shelves.map(shelf => (
        <div key={ shelf.key } className="bookshelf">
          <h2 className="bookshelf-title">{ shelf.name }</h2>

          { updateShelf(shelfkey).length === 0 ?
            (<div>no books on this shelf</div>)
            :
            (<div className="bookshelf-books">
                <ol className="books-grid">
                  <li>
                    {updateShelf(shelf.key).map(book => (
                      <Books
                        book={book}
                        books={books}
                        key={book.id}
                        onupdateShelf={this.UpdateShelf}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </li>
                </ol>
            </div>
            )
          }

        </div>
      ))}
      <Link to="/search" className="open-search">Add a book</Link>
    </div>
  </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Changeshelf.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import * as BooksAPI from './BooksAPI'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import Books from './Books.js'

export default class ChangeShelf extends Component {

  static propTypes = {
    book: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    books: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
    onChangeShelf: PropTypes.func.isRequired
}

updateShelf = (book, newShelf) => {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const newBooks = previousState.books.filter((b) => b.id !== 
book.id)
    newBooks.push({ book, newShelf })
    return { books: newBooks }
  })
  BooksAPI.update(book, newShelf)
}
moveBook = (shelf) => {
  const { books } = this.props
  return books.filter(book => book.shelf === shelf)
}

render() {
  const { book, books, updateShelf } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="book-shelf-changer">
        <select onChange={(event) => updateShelf(book, 
event.target.value)}>
          <option value="move" disabled>Move to...</option>
          <option value="Currently Reading">Currently Reading</option>
          <option value="Want To Read">Want to Read</option>
          <option value="Read">Read</option>
          <option value="none">None</option>
        </select>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: There isn't any `updateShelf` method in your `Bookshelf` component. Also, you are importing `ChangeShelf` but you are not using it. If you still not comfortable how props and state work, do not struggle with some kind of complex app like here. Just go to the official documentation and study it first.

Comment: Uhm.. there is updateShelf method in the Bookshelf component...?

updateShelf = (book, newShelf) => {
  this.setState(previousState => {
    const newBooks = previousState.books.filter((b) => b.id !== 
book.id)
    newBooks.push({ book, newShelf })
    return { books: newBooks }
  })
  BooksAPI.update(book, newShelf)
}
moveBook = (shelf) => {
  const { books } = this.props
  return books.filter(book => book.shelf === shelf)
}

render() { ....... <select onChange={(event) => updateShelf(book,

Comment: It is in `ChangeShelf` component not `Bookshelf` one. Am I missing something here?

Comment: The function itself is in ChangeShelf.js, but it's imported and used in Bookshelf.js, as well as selected in onChange in ChangeShelf.js... am I missing something?

Comment: You can't use methods like that from another component. You pass the methods as a prop to your child component and can use there as a prop. Importing a component does not provide any method in the main component like `Bookshelf`. This is why I've suggested studying the basic stuff. No offense :)

Comment: Okay gotcha, appreciate the kinda assistance, will read into passing method as props etc.

Comment: You are welcome. It will definitely help with understanding the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll try to explain ;)

Component `App`

- loads books and saves data in state;
- render uses imported component `<Bookshelf />`;
- Bookshelf gets `this.state.books` as `books` prop and **not existing** (in App) handler/method `this.updateShelf` as `onUpdateShelf` prop;

In `Bookshelf` you can use them by `this.props.books` and `this.props.onUpdateShelf`. This is **passing handler by prop**. It **lets call method in parent from child. It can be passed/used deeply.** Called method, async processes usually ends with new state (setState) which forces rerender (updating props passed to childs).

For simplicity `const { book, books, shelfkey } = this.props;` (in render) these props can be used by local identifiers `book` (instead `this.props.book`), `books`, `shelfkey`.

Problems:

- no `book` passed;
- no `shelfkey` passed;
- missing `book` and `updateShelf` defined by `propTypes` as required (we have `onUpdateShelf` instead, but passed missing method, undefined);
- `updateShelf` not defined, not passed (should be `this.props.updateShelf`), not defined locally (should be `this.updateShelf`);
- `updateShelf` used (expected) there as fn returning array while in `ChangeShelf` as event handler;

You can move `updateShelf` method from `ChangeShelf` to `App` and pass it as prop to Bookshelf, Search and deeper when needed.

Comment: This helps me make some more sense out of it, thanks!